# MongoRestore error: "Root directory must be a dump of a single database"

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

I'm new to MongoDB and I have hard time to backup my local DB and restore it on my server. I found the link on Mongo's website : http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools but I still have problems with the restore.

When I do my backup I call

```
mongodump --db Gen
```

Then I see that all the collections are dump in `/bin/dump/Gen` folder

I copy-paste from local to the server in the same folder the call

```
mongorestore --db Gen --drop --dbpath dump/Gen
```

But I get the following :
`Error : root directory must be a dump of a single database when specifying a db name with --db`

Comment: what if you change directory into dump/Gen and run it again with `--dbpath .`

Comment: you mean mongodump --db Gen --dbpath dump/Gen ? does not work...

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Ok I find out what I'm doing wrong :

I was doing

```
mongorestore --db Gen --drop --dbpath dump/Gen
```

But without the --dbpath it works just fine!

```
mongorestore --db Gen --drop dump/Gen
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Worth noting why, `--dbpath` sets the path of the **live database**, not the dumped data. You can do that to bypass connecting to the databsae.

Comment: Just for the record, the `--drop` is important: without it, already existing `_id`'s aren't replaced. That means changes to objects that already exist in the db you're restoring to would not be added.

Comment: is the 'Gen' mongodb actually being dropped? In mine case, on restore, i can see the previous records that was added after taking the dump. can you solve my issue here .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22424347/drop-whole-database-within-a-single-command-of-restoring-the-dump-of-mongodb

Comment: Ditto. So weird that it doesn't work when you explicitly declare the path using --dbpath ./dump

Answer (score 5):

I think your folder structure may be getting messed up when you try to move it.  For instance, this works for me:

```
$ ./mongodump --db Gen
$ ./mongorestore --db Gen --drop dump/Gen/
```

Can you try not moving the dump directory, and restoring from /bin/dump/Gen?

The directory you specify should have .bson files in it, e.g.,

```
$ ls /bin/dump/Gen
foo.bson  bar.bson  baz.bson
```

Comment: Hi Kristina, if I do it on my local computer it works fine, the db is restored and I don't get any error. The directory that I move has the .bson files in it. I can't do the restore since my dbs are only visible on local, can't find out how to "open" my server (win2008) so I can see it from the outside, I think I will start an other question for this one.

Comment: Okay.  The if statement before this error is literally "if (is_directory(p))" where p is a file/directory in dump/Gen.  Are you sure there are no subdirectories in there?

Answer (score 4):

This is what ended up working for me (`mydb` is the name of my database):

```
mongorestore --drop -db mydb mydbbackup/mydb/
```

After my `mongodump`:

```
mongodump -d mydb -o mydbbackup
```

Answer (score 3):

An additional note for whoever doesn't want to be annoyed by the error "root directory must be a dump of a single database when specifying a db name with --db"

When specifying --db and without --collection (restoring a whole database):
- the given path must be a directory path
- the directory must not contain any other files than .bson or .json. It took me a while to realize that the hidden .svn folder (if you use SVN) will mess up the script

Comment: Also had this problem, but in my case Mongo create mongo.lock file in this folder while I was trying to restore earlier, I've deleted the file and everything worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

It must be any other directory in a dump directory. So, remove the directory first and re-run the command `mongorestore -d db dump/db`

Answer (score -1):

Example:

```
./mongorestore -d db -c mycollection dump/db
```

will raise the following error

```
ERROR: ERROR: root directory must be a dump of a single collection
ERROR:        when specifying a collection name with --collection
```

you can remove the -c option to rolve this error.Beacuse dump/db specify the db, but not collection.

Comment: This does not fix anything. The error is talking about the -d option, not the -c option