# Restore done, but I don't see any database

Tags: mongodb

I run this

```
 mongorestore --db  dbName
```

and I got

> the --db and --collection args should only be used when restoring from
>   a BSON file. Other uses are deprecated and will not exist in the
>   future; use
>        --nsInclude instead

so I used

```
mongorestore --nsInclude   'dbName.*'
```

and I got

> 2018-01-06T21:28:02.106+0200    using default 'dump' directory
>   2018-01-06T21:28:02.142+0200    preparing collections to restore from
>   2018-01-06T21:28:02.147+0200    done

but I don't see any db of dbName that created.

Comment: Hi Dave, Did you figure this out? I'm getting the same thing. I haven't found anything that worked yet.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here [MongoRestore error: "Root directory must be a dump of a single database"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884418/mongorestore-of-a-db-causing-me-trouble)

```
mongorestore --db you_db_name --drop dump/you_db_name
```